# What is causing the failed to find conversion error from unknown to text for my union statement?

Tags: postgresql, recursion, union

EDIT: I am now getting an error "failed to find conversion function from unknown to text" when I do the union at the bottom, but the tables have identical columns so I can't figure out what is causing the issue. Any suggestions? Everything I've looked at indicates this should work. Is it possible the issue is when I change the ID number and LEG name for the two columns?

```
WITH RECURSIVE "child" AS (
    SELECT "ConsultantDisplayID",
           "FirstName", 
           "LastName" ,
           "ParentPersonDisplayID"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant"
    WHERE "ConsultantDisplayID" = '4019'
UNION 
    SELECT c."ConsultantDisplayID", 
           c."FirstName" ,
           c."LastName" ,
           c."ParentPersonDisplayID"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant" AS c 
    JOIN "child" AS cd 
    ON c."ParentPersonDisplayID" = cd."ConsultantDisplayID"),
    
"sponsor" AS (
    SELECT 
        "child".*,
--      c1."ConsultantDisplayID",
        c1."FirstName" AS "Sponsor FirstName",
        c1."LastName" AS "Sponsor LastName",
        'JJones' AS "LEG"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant" AS c1
    LEFT JOIN "child" 
    ON c1."ConsultantDisplayID" = "child"."ParentPersonDisplayID"), 
    
"promo" AS (
    SELECT "sponsor"."ConsultantDisplayID",
           "sponsor"."FirstName", 
           "sponsor"."LastName" ,
           pr."Rank" AS "First Time Promo Consultant New Rank",
           pr."EffectiveDate",
           "sponsor"."ParentPersonDisplayID",
           "sponsor"."Sponsor FirstName",
           "sponsor"."Sponsor LastName",
           "sponsor"."LEG"
    FROM "sponsor"
    LEFT JOIN "all_time_first_promotion" as pr
    ON "sponsor"."ConsultantDisplayID" = pr."PersonDisplayID"
),

"child2" AS (
    SELECT "ConsultantDisplayID",
           "FirstName", 
           "LastName" ,
           "ParentPersonDisplayID"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant"
    WHERE "ConsultantDisplayID" = '3030'
UNION 
    SELECT c."ConsultantDisplayID", 
           c."FirstName" ,
           c."LastName" ,
           c."ParentPersonDisplayID"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant" AS c 
    JOIN "child2" AS cd2 
    ON c."ParentPersonDisplayID" = cd2."ConsultantDisplayID"),

"sponsor2" AS (
    SELECT 
        "child2".*,
--      c1."ConsultantDisplayID",
        c1."FirstName" AS "Sponsor FirstName",
        c1."LastName" AS "Sponsor LastName",
        'JJones' AS "LEG"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant" AS c1
    LEFT JOIN "child2" 
    ON c1."ConsultantDisplayID" = "child2"."ParentPersonDisplayID"),
    
"promo2" AS (
    SELECT "sponsor2"."ConsultantDisplayID",
           "sponsor2"."FirstName", 
           "sponsor2"."LastName" ,
           pr."Rank" AS "First Time Promo Consultant New Rank",
           pr."EffectiveDate",
           "sponsor2"."ParentPersonDisplayID",
           "sponsor2"."Sponsor FirstName",
           "sponsor2"."Sponsor LastName",
           "sponsor2"."LEG"
    FROM "sponsor2"
    LEFT JOIN "all_time_first_promotion" as pr
    ON "sponsor2"."ConsultantDisplayID" = pr."PersonDisplayID"
)
    
SELECT * 
FROM "promo"
--WHERE "promo"."First Time Promo Consultant New Rank" IS NOT NULL 

UNION

SELECT *
FROM "promo2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect.  Your CTEs should be at the top with your `UNION` below them.

You will need to rename at least one set of your recursive CTEs to make this work.  It should look something like the following:

```
WITH RECURSIVE "child" AS (
    SELECT "ConsultantDisplayID",
           "FirstName", 
           "LastName" ,
           "ParentPersonDisplayID"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant"
    WHERE "ConsultantDisplayID" = '4019'
UNION 
    SELECT c."ConsultantDisplayID", 
           c."FirstName" ,
           c."LastName" ,
           c."ParentPersonDisplayID"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant" AS c 
    JOIN "child" AS cd 
    ON c."ParentPersonDisplayID" = cd."ConsultantDisplayID"),
    
"sponsor" AS (
    SELECT 
        "child".*,
        c1."FirstName" AS "Sponsor FirstName",
        c1."LastName" AS "Sponsor LastName",
        'JJones' AS "LEG"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant" AS c1
    LEFT JOIN "child" 
    ON c1."ConsultantDisplayID" = "child"."ParentPersonDisplayID"), 
    
"promo" AS (
    SELECT "sponsor"."ConsultantDisplayID",
           "sponsor"."FirstName", 
           "sponsor"."LastName" ,
           pr."Rank" AS "First Time Promo Consultant New Rank",
           pr."EffectiveDate",
           "sponsor"."ParentPersonDisplayID",
           "sponsor"."Sponsor FirstName",
           "sponsor"."Sponsor LastName",
           "sponsor"."LEG"
    FROM "sponsor"
    LEFT JOIN "all_time_first_promotion" as pr
    ON "sponsor"."ConsultantDisplayID" = pr."PersonDisplayID"
),
"child2" AS (
    SELECT "ConsultantDisplayID",
           "FirstName", 
           "LastName" ,
           "ParentPersonDisplayID"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant"
    WHERE "ConsultantDisplayID" = '3030'
UNION 
    SELECT c."ConsultantDisplayID", 
           c."FirstName" ,
           c."LastName" ,
           c."ParentPersonDisplayID"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant" AS c 
    JOIN "child2" AS cd 
    ON c."ParentPersonDisplayID" = cd."ConsultantDisplayID"),
    
"sponsor2" AS (
    SELECT 
        "child".*,
        c1."FirstName" AS "Sponsor FirstName",
        c1."LastName" AS "Sponsor LastName",
        'CKeck' AS "LEG"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant" AS c1
    LEFT JOIN "child2" as child
    ON c1."ConsultantDisplayID" = "child"."ParentPersonDisplayID"), 
    
"promo2" AS (
    SELECT "sponsor"."ConsultantDisplayID",
           "sponsor"."FirstName", 
           "sponsor"."LastName" ,
           pr."Rank" AS "First Time Promo Consultant New Rank",
           pr."EffectiveDate",
           "sponsor"."ParentPersonDisplayID",
           "sponsor"."Sponsor FirstName",
           "sponsor"."Sponsor LastName",
           "sponsor"."LEG"
    FROM "sponsor2" as sponsor
    LEFT JOIN "all_time_first_promotion" as pr
    ON "sponsor"."ConsultantDisplayID" = pr."PersonDisplayID"
)
  
SELECT * FROM "promo"
WHERE "First Time Promo Consultant New Rank" is not null

UNION

    
SELECT * FROM "promo2"
WHERE "First Time Promo Consultant New Rank" is not null
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! I went back and renamed the second set of CTEs and everything ran until I did the union at the end. Any idea why I'm getting an error that says "failed to find conversion function from unknown to text" when I do the union at the end? Everything before that runs

Comment: @ekeckeisen  I am not seeing the problem.  Could it be that `'CKeck'` in the `sponsor2` CTE needs to be cast?  `'CKeck'::text`  Can you please put an update to your question showing your final `UNION` query?  The `notnull` was the wrong syntax in the original, and I have updated my answer.